# link virtual piano with midi-Keyboard

Tags: reactjs

need to link my midi piano to virtual piano...
I don't how to create an event to do this.
I have the connexion with web-midi and react-piano, but i don't how to link  the midi piano with virtual piano. I get the input information and the key number, but i don't know how to play virtual piano when i click on piano midi.

```
const noteRange = {
  first: MidiNumbers.fromNote('c1'),
  last: MidiNumbers.fromNote('f5'),
};

export default class ResponsivePiano extends React.Component {

  state={
    midiNote:'',
  }
  onNoteOnMidiKeyboard=(event) => {
    this.setState({
      midiNote: event.note
    });
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    WebMidi.enable((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(' WebMidi n\'a pas pu être activé. ', err);
      } else {
        console.log(' WebMidi activé! ');
      }

      const input = WebMidi.inputs[0];
      input.addListener('noteon', 'all', this.onNoteOnMidiKeyboard.bind(this));

      console.log(WebMidi.inputs);
      console.log(WebMidi.outputs);

    });

  }


  render(){
    const { midiNote } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <p>
        Midi number: {midiNote.number}


        </p>
        <DimensionsProvider>
          {({ containerWidth, containerHeight }) => (
            <SoundfontProvider
              instrumentName="acoustic_grand_piano"
              audioContext={audioContext}
              hostname={soundfontHostname}
              render={({ isLoading, playNote, stopNote }) => (
                <Piano
                  onChange={this.onCurrentNote}
                  noteRange={noteRange}
                  width={containerWidth}
                  onPlayNote={playNote}
                  onStopNote={stopNote}
                  disabled={isLoading}
                />
              )}
            />
          )}
        </DimensionsProvider>
        {}
      </div>
    );

  }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

react-piano accepts a `playbackNotes` prop which should do the trick. When you set those notes, they're played back.

```
<Piano
  // ...other props
  playbackNotes={[this.state.midiNote.number]}
/>
```

If you ever have any questions about react-piano, please feel free to cross-post to the [react-piano github issues](https://github.com/iqnivek/react-piano/issues)! I keep an eye on that more closely.